# a more extensive recursion/generics question

Tags: java, generics

Based on the question asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650532/recursive-java-generics-between-two-classes), I have a second, more complex one (at least in my opinion). To make reading (and answering) easier, I will, however, restate the complete code example here:

Let us begin by defining a set of classes/interfaces:

```
public interface Node<NT extends Node<NT, ET>, ET extends Edge<NT, ET>> {
  /* internal datastructures here */
}

public interface Edge<NT extends Node<NT, ET>, ET extends Edge<NT, ET>> {
  /* internal datastructures here */
}

public interface Graph<NT extends Node<NT, ET>, ET extends Edge<NT, ET>> {
  /* internal datastructures here */
}

public class JunctionNode implements Node<JunctionNode, RoadEdge> {
}

public class RoadEdge implements Edge<JunctionNode, RoadEdge> {
}

public class StreetGraph implements Graph<JunctionNode, RoadEdge> {
}

public class PTNode implements Node<PTNode, PTEdge> {
}

public class PTEdge implements Edge<PTNode, PTEdge> {
}

public class PTGraph implements Graph<PTNode, PTEdge> {
}
```

I now need to define an intermodal graph, i.e. a graph containing PTEdges as well as RoadEdges. In my opinion, I would do this by stating

```
public class IntermodalGraph implements Graph<Node, Edge> {
}
```

Here the compiler complaints on Node and Edge, since Node is defined to have two type parameters whereupon one is derived from the second type (here Edge). This means, I would have to state

```
public class IntermodalGraph implements Graph<Node<Node, Edge>, Edge> {
}
```

So far, the first type parameter (Node) is ok, but the second one (Edge) fails since edges takes two type parameters again, the first one derived from Node. So, I would write

```
public class IntermodalGraph implements Graph<Node<Node, Edge>, Edge<Node<Node, Edge>>, Edge> {
}
```

Now, the second type parameter is ok, but the first one is (obviously) "bad" again.

In the end, I would like to achieve some code like

```
IntermodalGraph ig = new IntermodalGraph();
ig.add(new PTEdge());
ig.add(new RoadEdge());

Set<Edge> edges = ig.getEdges();
```

So does anybody have an idea how to achieve this while keeping type safe?

lg,
Matthias

Comment: It seems to me that you want to violate your own interface: `interface Node<NT extends Node<NT, ET>, ET extends Edge<NT, ET>>` should have nodes and edges of the same type, but you want to use mixed types of node/edge. You should probably redefine your interfaces instead of abusing a weakness of Java generics to get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your classes already specify the generics, you could declare your `IntermodalGraph` class as

```
public class IntermodalGraph<NT extends Node<NT, ET>, ET extends Edge<NT, ET>> implements Graph<NT, ET> {
}
```

And this should not throw any warnings.

** **EDIT** **

You can't accomplish what you want, that is having

```
IntermodalGraph ig = new IntermodalGraph();
ig.add(new PTEdge());
ig.add(new RoadEdge());

Set<Edge> edges = ig.getEdges();
```

not throw any `unchecked` warnings, unless you add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotations. But, it *is still* valid Java syntax and will work; the generic `NT` will default to `Node` and `ET` to `Edge`

Comment: You are right, this does not throw warnings, but I cannot instantiate the class IntermodalGraph without warnings since as soon as I write `IntermodalGraph<?,?> ig = new IntermodalGraph<NT, ET>();` I have to specify NT and ET, which I cannot. In fact, your proposal is just a shifting of the above described definition problem of the type parameters to another place in the code; namely the place where the instantiation takes place.

Comment: @Matthias, Java is pretty soft with generics. Other languages are not as forgiving... Bottom line is that I doubt you will find a solution to have a generic-less instanciation from your declarations. Like I said, they are just warnings; the methods will default to `Node` and `Edge` just like you want regardless...

Comment: thanks. I was not sure that NT and ET will default to Node and Edge. But since this is exactly what I finally want, using @SuppressWarnings is ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by toto, you define a type checkable contract and then proceed to break it -- and the compiler intervenes. A type safe solution is to simply split the contract in two, a weaker and a stricter one: A `Graph<N extends Node<?, ?>, E extends Edge<?, ?>>` interface as well as a `StrictGraph<N extends Node<N, E>, E extends Edge<N, E>>` interface which extends `Graph<N, E>`.